# FirebaseJobDispatcher does not schedule job and gives error that there are too many tasks scheduled for this package

Tags: android, firebase, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

When I try to schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher it gives error that there are too many tasks scheduled for this package. I have 5 jobs scheduled.

The exact error I get is as follow -

> NetworkScheduler: Too many tasks scheduled for this package. Not scheduling: [package.name/com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver:UpdateCheckinFailed,u0]

How should I solve this issue, I can't reduce the number of jobs as all those jobs work independently for syncing from local device to server and I close them properly when sync is completed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Job builder try 
    *setReplaceCurrent(false)*

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. You can look here for more details https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/155